# How to use mocha to test jquery post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, mocha.js

I use jQuery to send form info into my server php API. Now I need to write a mocha test for it and I am really new to the mocha and jQuery. What do I need to do? Here is my code:

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="http://140.115.xxx.xx/FinalProject/FetchUserData.php">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name ="username" id="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name ="password">
    <button type="submit" id="login-button">Login</button><br>
    <li id="showerror"></li>
    <a id="goToRegister" href="register.html" >Register</a>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $form = $('form');
    $form.submit(function(){
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
            if(response == true) {
                var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
                window.location.href="main.html?" + username;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('showerror').innerHTML = "invalid username or password";
            }
        }, 'json');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Just an FYI - your `li` element is invalid as it's not contained in a `ul` or `ol`.

Comment: It will only show up when user login failed.

Comment: Ok, but it will still mean that the HTML of your page will be invalid which can affect the JS, the CSS and the SEO rank.

Comment: you are right thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an awesome mocking tool [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/), it has [Fake XMLHttpRequest](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server).

Comment: Thanks! i will use it first. but after i use sinon to test connection, what about the code testing ??

Comment: You just need to simulate server response with `FakeXMLHttpRequest` API and your code will run like it received response from server with your fake data.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to read the document and it's still a mess to me. Can you explain further about how to use sinon to fake the server response ?

Comment: Thank you very much!!!
I still want to know about the test. So I use command to input "mocha", and it will simulate I click the submit button. And this script will response a fake response to let the program go through.  Is my explanation correct??

Comment: Sinon fake server will respond on `server.respond()` call.